# Cryptography: ciphering in python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

Problem statement: Every upper case alphabet shifts to the left, for example if the alphabet D was left shifted by 3, it will become A, and E would become B, and so on..

I got the first two test cases correctly, but I got stuck at the third one that had a pound sign.

My trial:

```py
sh = int(input())
s = input()
n = ""
for char in s:
    val = ord(char)-sh
    if char != " ":
        if 65 <= val <= 90:
            n += chr(val)
        else:
            if val < 65:
                if '0' <= char <= '9':
                    n += char
                else:
                    n += chr(90 - (65 - val - 1))
    else:
        n += char
print(n)
```

**Test case 1:**

```
(in1)>> 3
(in2)>> H3LL0 W0RLD
(out)>> E3II0 T0OIA
```

**Test case 2:**

```
(in1)>> 6
(in2)>> THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG
(out)>> NBY KOCWE VLIQH ZIR DOGJM IPYL NBY FUTS XIA
```

**Test case 3:**

```
(input_num_1)>> 2
(input_num_2)>> H4IGDFDNO£PJNHVDKHZPDOPG2
(ExpectedOut)>> F4GEBDBLM\-62\-93NHLFTBIFXNBMNE2
(My_output_.)>> F4GEBDBLMNHLFTBIFXNBMNE2
```

Your help & and time to review this is seriously appreciated.
Thank you.

---

Edit:
To add more clarity, I've added what my code yields as an output under the expected output, and to be specific, how/why is `£` mapped to `\-62\-93` ?

Comment: A pound sign: (£) is U+00A3 in Unicode.  When written in UTF-8 that is 0xC2 0xA3, which is what you are seeing, converted to signed base 10.

Comment: Yeah I figured, I added this conversion bit to the code and it works now, Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't beat a good Caesar Cipher question. You're on the right track but I would use inbuilt checks on the character to quickly decide what to do with it.

```
sh = int(input())
s = input()
n = ""
for char in s:
    val = ord(char)-sh
    if char.isupper() and char.isalpha():
        if 65 <= val <= 90:
            n += chr(val)
        else:
            n += chr(90 - (65 - val - 1))
    else:
        n += char
print(n)
```

Comment: Thanks pal! I'll consider this of course! note that I've added an Edit that includes the exact part that I cannot match (the pound sign).